# BLE android read readCharacteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, android-ble

I Try to devlope android app to read from cycling sensor ,
if anyone can help plz . its connect to the sensor but cant read the characteristic.
i dont know how to read the characterestic value . its a speed sensor sor i want to be notify or read (i dont know the exact its read or notify)

///////////////////////////LOGCAT////////////////////////////

```
 onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=F7:88:0B:34:04:5F
onScanResult: F7:88:0B:34:04:5F:35007-2 
connect() - device: F7:88:0B:34:04:5F, auto: false
registerApp()
registerApp() - UUID=b71dffd9-b87e-4ac9-9985-28ad9934745b
onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=F7:88:0B:34:04:5F
discoverServices() - device: F7:88:0B:34:04:5
 onSearchComplete() = Device=F7:88:0B:34:04:5F Status=0

//////////////////////LIST ALL SERVISES/////////////////////
setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a5b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
```

this is the code ;

```
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                      super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        
                      if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                          gatt.discoverServices();
                      } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                          ScanningEnd = false;
                      }
                  }
        
                  @Override
                  public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                      super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        
                      List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
                      Log.e("onServicesDiscovered", "Services count: "+services.size());
        
                      for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
                          Log.d(TAG, "Found Service " + service.getUuid().toString());
                          for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic mcharacteristic :service.getCharacteristics())
                          {
                              Log.d(TAG, "Found Characteristic " + mcharacteristic.getUuid().toString());}}
   
                     characteristicNotifi = gatt.getService(NOTIF_SERVICE)
                              .getCharacteristic(NOTIF_CHARACTERESTIC);
        
                      gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicNotifi, true);
                      gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristicNotifi);
        
                  }

@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                      super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);              
                      if (characteristic.equals(characteristicNotifi)) {
        
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}});}}};
        
        
              @Override
              public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                  super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
              }
        
          };
    
        }

.
```

Comment: Pleaase hare what you've done so far. Stackoverflow is here to help but not to create the whole application for you.

Comment: Have you tried following the [Android BLE Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-ble-data#java)?

Comment: thx for answer .i try to make this code by by Ariel Malka --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215063/android-ble-readcharacteristic-is-not-working and this is the code:

Comment: @AdamDOGLA the code Ariel used is not working as he stated in his question. Please try to follow the Android guide I linked above

Comment: @Michael Kotzjanhi .thx for your answer. i edit the question im able to connect to the sensor and enable the notify but i dont know how to read the value plz some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27075669/7473793) for how to subscribe to notifications correctly using Android.

You need to do two steps to activate notifications on both the Android phone and the remote BLE device:

1. Enable notification handling on your Android phone:

```
gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicNotifi, true);
```

2. Enable notifications on your BLE device for every characteristic you want:

```
// 0x2902 org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristicNotifi.getDescriptor(uuid);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

These steps are also described in the [Android BLE Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-ble-data#notification), but the second step is a little bit obscured, unfortunately.

This should be enough to get a callback on your `onCharacteristicChanged`.

Comment: Kotzjanhi thx for your help . its work by add this descriptor.